# R: make a loop on a list and a number

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

Using R, I am doing a loop on `i` that runs along `listValues` that is a set of values in the following way:

```
for(i in listValues) { bla bla bla }
```

But at some point, inside the loop, I need the `i` to be a number (and not a value from a list) to fill a dataframe:

```
dataframe[i,] =  5
```

with `i`, being a number this time (`i` going from `1` to `length(listValues)`)

Is there any easy way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: `for(i in seq_along(listValues))`? In the loop access the list members with `listValues[[i]]`.

Comment: I need the `i` to stay a name. I have many `paste` and  `eval` through the loop and I don't want to change that. Maybe a solution would be to create a second variable `j` such as `j in  seq_along(listValues)` ?

Comment: I believe it would be simpler to have `lvals <- listValues[[i]]` as the first instruction of the loop and use `paste`, `eval`, etc on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way without doing a new loop is to use `which`:

```
df.summary[which(listValues==i),] = 5
```